# Flamingo, How to put Jtooltips on JCommandbuttons

Tags: java, swing, radiance-flamingo

When you put the tool tip to the Jcommandbutton, using the settooltiptext function, UnsupportedOperation exception occurs

```
enter code here
```

band declare

```
    JRibbonBand band = new JRibbonBand("File", null);
```

Jcommandbutton

```
    JCommandButton btn_open = new JCommandButton("Open",
            getResizableIcon("Open.png"));

    btn_open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (text_change) {
                open();
            } else {
                int i = save_check();
                if (i == 0) {
                    save();
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    open();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Action Ac_Open = new AbstractAction() {//hot key

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (text_change) {
                open();
            } else {
                int i = save_check();
                if (i == 0) {
                    save();
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    open();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Ac_Open.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control O"));
    btn_open.getActionMap().put("Open", Ac_Open);
    btn_open.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            (KeyStroke) Ac_Open.getValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY), "Open");
    JToolTip tip = new JToolTip();
    tip.setTipText("O");
    btn_open.add(tip);
    btn_open.setToolTipText("O");
```

Properties of the band && task

```
    band.addCommandButton(btn_open, RibbonElementPriority.MEDIUM);

    band.setResizePolicies((List) Arrays.asList(
            new CoreRibbonResizePolicies.None(band.getControlPanel()),
            new IconRibbonBandResizePolicy(band.getControlPanel())));

    RibbonTask task1 = new RibbonTask("Menu", band);

    this.getRibbon().addTask(task1);
```

I think there seems to be a problem in the part of the list to change the arrangement.

Comment: Please include a stack trace of the `UnsupportedOperationException` to make things easier for users trying to answer your question.